# NSLayoutConstraint "installed" property in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is the "installed" property only for enabling/disabling constraints for different size classes and not for runtime changes?

I want to have multiple sets of constraints that I enable/disable based on some condition on a view inside an UITableViewCell.

But if I design them all in IB and uncheck installed for some of them and then try to activate/deactivate them during runtime, nothing happens. I am storing strong references and I have tried numerous setNeedsDisplay/setNeedsUpdateConstraints on the different views.

The only way to make it work is to have all of them installed and the extra ones be with priority of 999, to avoid errors. Then I can activate/deactivate them during runtime with no problems.

Comment: I just did a quick test, putting both `leading` and `centerX` constraints on a button, with the `leading` constraint NOT checkmarked as `Installed` --- no problem activating one / deactivating the other and vice-versa. I'd suggest starting with ONE constraint, and get that working... then try a group of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `isActive` property. Remember to do this on the main thread by using `DispatchQueue.main.async{ ... }`

Answer (score -1):

You can activate your constraints if you have an IBOutlet for each one of them.

You need to be carefull though and disable those that will conflict before activate your constraint otherwise it will fail, that most likely is your issue.